# Image doesn't show when changing

Tags: php, html, css

```
<div id="logo">
<?php if($jw_logo_textual == 'on'){ ?>
<h1>
   <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
</h1>
```

I want to change a picture in a header.php (banner) when I change '/images/logo.png' to the url I want, it doesn't show up. While I'm sure the url is correct. can anyone help?

```
 <?php }else{ ?>
 <?php if($jw_logo_image != ''){ $logo_img = $jw_logo_image; }
     else{ $logo_img = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png'; }
 ?> 
 <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $logo_img; ?>" alt="" />
 </a>
 <?php } ?>

</div><!-- #logo -->
```

Comment: What's the actual URL of img you get? You can see it in the page's source (Ctrl-U in Firefox, for example).

Comment: http://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/themename/images/logo.png
but i want it to be http://i47.tinypic.com/xx.png

Comment: What exactly is the url you want, and what do you write when using it ?

Comment: I change /images/logo.png with http://i47.tinypic.com/xx.png

Comment: you can change the logo in der wordpress admin panel directly. no need to fiddle with the php instead.

Comment: For some reason not with this theme

Comment: Do you have http:// appended to the start of the new logo url? also can you print the resultant html source?

Comment: by the way : i47.tinypic.com/xx.png doesn't work for me

Comment: Place your image in images folder of the installation and give th address like images/xx.png .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have an internet url, you need to remove

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

Its only necessary when you have a local adress

Comment: Thaaanks, I don't know anything 'bout php. Lifesaver & Hero!